# В чем разница между cat 1 <2 3 и cat <1 2 3

Tags: bash, shell

Есть три файла – 1, 2 и 3.

В файле 1 – hello, в файле 2 - lovely, 3 - world

**Команда 1**

```
cat 1 <2 3
```

выводит

```
Hello
World
```

Куда девается содержимое файла 2?

**Команда 2**

```
cat <1 2 3
```

выводит

```
lovely
world
```

Куда девается содержимое файла 1?

Comment: Пробел после `<` поставьте

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ещё интереснее:

```
$ cat <2
lovely
```

что при этом происходит? оболочка создаёт новый процесс, загружает в него исполняемый блоб `/bin/cat` (ну или где он в вашей системе находится), и в качестве *stdin* этому процессу передаёт дескриптор открытого (оболочкой) файла с именем `2`.

с точки зрения запущенного процесса *cat* ему не передано ни одного аргумента. его действия в этом случае (см. `$ man cat`):

> With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.

вольный перевод:

> если среди аргументов не указано имён файлов, или если аргумент равен `-`, читать из *stdin*.

вот и получается, что процесс *cat* прочитает *stdin* (фактически — содержимое файла с именем `2`) и выдаст его в свой *stdout*.

но стоит добавить хотя бы ещё один аргумент:

```
$ cat <2 1
hello
```

процесс *cat* (самостоятельно) прочитает только содержимое файла с именем `1` (и выдаст его в свой *stdout*), а заботливо переданный для него оболочкой *stdin* просто проигнорирует.

---

а чтобы не проигнорировал, можно явно добавить аргумент `-`:

```
$ cat <2 1 -
hello
lovely
```

процесс *cat* «увидит» два аргумента: `1` и `-`, и выдаст в свой *stdout* сначала содержимое файла с именем `1`, а затем то, что прочтёт из *stdin* (куда оболочка передаёт ему содержимое файла с именем `2`).

---

доп. чтение:

- `$ man cat`
- про [перенаправление ввода-вывода в стандарте posix](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07)